# adding foreign key to mysql giving error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `survey` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`createdby`) REFERENCES `easysurvey`.`user`(`UserName`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1215 - Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, i add UNSIGNED to indexed column (for UserName)

I think, fields with relations must have same properties

Answer (score 1):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys

Don't know French well, but my guess user.UserName isn't indexed